# Suggestion to vectorize a Python function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I wrote the following function, which takes as inputs three 1D array (namely `int_array`, `x`, and `y`) and a number `lim`. The output is a number as well.

```python
def integrate_to_lim(int_array, x, y, lim):
    if lim >= np.max(x):
        res = 0.0
    if lim <= np.min(x):
        res = int_array[0]
    else:
        index = np.argmax(x > lim)    # To find the first element of x larger than lim
        partial = int_array[index]
        slope = (y[index-1] - y[index]) / (x[index-1] - x[index])
        rest = (x[index] - lim) * (y[index] + (lim - x[index]) * slope / 2.0)
        res = partial + rest
    return res
```

Basically, outside form the limit cases `lim>=np.max(x)` and `lim<=np.min(x)`, the idea is that the function finds the index of the first value of the array `x` larger than `lim` and then uses it to make some simple calculations.

In my case, however `lim` can also be a fairly big 2D array (shape ~2000 times ~1000 elements)

**I would like to rewrite it such that it makes the same calculations for the case that** `lim` **is a 2D array**.
Obviously, the output should also be a 2D array of the same shape of `lim`.

I am having a real struggle figuring out how to vectorize it.
I would like to stick only to the `numpy` package.

*PS I want to **vectorize** my function because efficiency is important and as I understand using for loops is not a good choice in this regard*.

## Edit: my attempt

I was not aware of the function `np.take`, which made the task way easier.
Here is my brutal attempt that seems to work (suggestions on how to clean up or to make the code faster are more than welcome).

```python
def integrate_to_lim_vect(int_array, x, y, lim_mat):
    lim_mat = np.asarray(lim_mat)    # Make sure that it is an array
    
    shape_3d = list(lim_mat.shape) + [1]
    x_3d = np.ones(shape_3d) * x    # 3 dimensional version of x
    lim_3d = np.expand_dims(lim_mat, axis=2) * np.ones(x_3d.shape)   # also 3d
    
    # I use np.argmax on the 3d matrices (is there a simpler way?)
    index_mat = np.argmax(x_3d > lim_3d, axis=2)
    
    # Silly calculations
    partial = np.take(int_array, index_mat)
    y1_mat = np.take(y, index_mat)
    y2_mat = np.take(y, index_mat - 1)
    x1_mat = np.take(x, index_mat)
    x2_mat = np.take(x, index_mat - 1)
    slope = (y1_mat - y2_mat) / (x1_mat - x2_mat)
    rest = (x1_mat - lim_mat) * (y1_mat + (lim_mat - x1_mat) * slope / 2.0)
    res = partial + rest
    
    # Make the cases with np.select
    condlist = [lim_mat >= np.max(x), lim_mat <= np.min(x)]
    choicelist = [0.0, int_array[0]]    # Shoud these options be a 2d matrix?
    output = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=res)
    return output
```

I am aware that if the limit is larger than the maximum value in the array `np.argmax` returns the index zero (leading to wrong results). This is why I used `np.select` to check and correct for these cases.

**Is it necessary to define the three dimensional matrices** `x_3d` **and **`lim_3d`**, or there is a simpler way to find the 2D matrix of the indices** `index_mat`**?**

Suggestions, especially to improve the way I *expanded the dimension of the arrays*, are welcome.

Comment: The basic approach is to rewrite as many of the operations inside the function in a way that works with the full 2d arrays, as opposed to just one 1d at a time.  I don't know of any short cuts or drop-in tools.  It's a mix of working from the bottom up, and stepping back and looking at the problem from an outside perspective, as something operating on 2d arrays rather than a list of 1ds.

Comment: I edited my question with an attempt of the solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this using two tricks. First, a 2d array can be easily [flattened](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) to a 1d array, and then your answers can be converted back into a 2d array with [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Next, your use of `argmax` suggests that your array is sorted. Then you can find your full set of indices using [digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). Thus instead of a single index, you will get a complete array of indices. All the calculations you are doing are intrinsically supported as array operations in numpy, so that should not cause any problems.

You will have to specifically look at the limiting cases. If those are rare enough, then it might be okay to let the answers be derived by the default formula (they will be garbage values), and then replace them with the actual values you desire.